# Fitnesse Maven Linux run

Tags: java, linux, maven, fitnesse

I am trying to run FitNesse in CentOS using this profile:

```
    <profile>
            <id>fitnesse</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-fitnesse</id>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <tasks>
                                        <echo taskname="fitnesse" message="Starting FitNesse..." />
                                        <java classname="fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain"
                                            classpathref="maven.runtime.classpath" fork="true">
                                            <arg line="-p 9595" />                                              
                                            <arg line="-d ." />
                                        </java>
                                    </tasks>
                                </configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>               
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.fitnesse.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-classpath-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
```

I am using maven.classpath to add the dependency jars into Fitnesse

```
         ${maven.classpath}
```

But in this case i am getting

```
         undefined variable: maven.classpath
```

Note: I am able to see FitNesse wiki page.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by maven classpath has not been set? The test run, when you click Test or Suite in wiki, does have all jars on classpath which are maven dependencies?

Comment: please look into my edited question

Answer (score 0):

To use the plugin you have to make sure it is available to the wiki (I usually use maven dependency plugin to copy it to the wiki's `plugins` directory). Just adding it as a maven dependency does not suffice.

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-plugins</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>org.fitnesse.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-classpath-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>${maven-classpath-plugin.version}</version>
                                <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
                                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/wiki/plugins</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Furthermore you have to (copied from the [README](https://github.com/amolenaar/fitnesse-maven-classpath#how-to-use)):

- Add the following line to plugins.properties:

  `SymbolTypes = fitnesse.wikitext.widgets.MavenClasspathSymbolType`
- Refer to the pom file as follows:

  `!pomFile /path/to/pom.xml`

  you can define the file as `pom.xml@compile` to include a specific scope.